# Rails Capistrano deploy error: fails on rake asset:precompile, in named scope with lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, asset-pipeline

A previously-working Rails 3.1 app is now failing to deploy. The Capistrano `deploy:assets:precompile` task encounters an error "`Could not find table 'users'`".

I have used `rake --trace` to pin this error down on a newly-added named scope in the `users` model:

```
scope :find_by_skill_offered, lambda { |skill_id|
  joins(:skills).where("user_skills.offered = ? AND skills.id = ?", 'true', skill_id)
}
```

It seems to me that the rake task may be trying to execute the lambda, before the database is linked, and therefore failing.

This sounds like a similar problem to [this problem with factory_girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761622/rake-dbmigrate-produces-rake-aborted-could-not-find-table-error), i.e. code being executed before the database exists, but I can't understand why a lambda would be executed before it is actually called.

The stack trace shows the construction of Devise routes in there as well, so maybe it's related to that, but it seems strange that routing code is being run as part of `deploy:assets:precompile`, or am I missing something about how the pipeline works?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This also occurs with local `rake assets:precompile` (I normally only build assets on the server).

**Full error output and trace:**

```
  * 18:47:58 == Currently executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747 && rake --trace RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
  servers: ["87.106.100.151"]
  [87.106.100.151] executing command
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] ** Execute assets:precompile
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] ** Invoke environment (first_time)
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] ** Execute environment
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] rake aborted!
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] Could not find table 'users'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:387:in `table_structure'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:270:in `columns'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `yield'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `default'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `columns'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:722:in `column_names'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:735:in `column_methods_hash'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1101:in `all_attributes_exists?'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:886:in `respond_to?'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:193:in `valid_scope_name?'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:175:in `scope'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747/app/models/user.rb:6:in `<class:User>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:528:in `block in initialize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `yield'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `default'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `[]'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:595:in `constantize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise.rb:259:in `get'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:101:in `to'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:96:in `modules'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:113:in `routes'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:82:in `initialize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise.rb:289:in `new'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise.rb:289:in `add_mapping'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:191:in `block in devise_for'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:190:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:190:in `devise_for'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747/config/routes.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:257:in `instance_exec'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:257:in `eval_block'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:234:in `draw'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in load_paths'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `call'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/releases/20111010174747/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /home/backscratchers/development/backscratchers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
*** [err :: 87.106.100.151] Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Comment: I have solved this by replacing the lambda function with a class method:

    `def self.find_by_skill_offered(skill_id)
      joins(:skills).where("user_skills.offered = ? AND skills.id = ?", 'true', skill_id)
    }`

It seems this is the preferred approach for Rails 3.1 and beyond.

If anyone can work out why the previous error was occurring though, I think it would be useful - could this be a bug in Devise? In case it is, I have created an issue on github for them to have a look at (and dismiss if irrelevant!): https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by replacing the lambda function with a class method:

```
def self.find_by_skill_offered(skill_id)
  joins(:skills).where("user_skills.offered = ? AND skills.id = ?", 'true', skill_id)
}
```

It seems this is the preferred approach for Rails 3.1 and beyond.

In case it was a bug in Devise, I created [an issue on GitHub](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1373), and apparently using a name like `find_by_*` may have been screwing things up.

I like using the same naming as Rails autogenerated find functions (although really this is a `find_all_by_*` because it returns an array), but as this seems to be dodgy, perhaps it should be avoided.

Sorry not to have definitive answers on the error.