# Can't rake migrations: Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up an existing rails app on a new workstations. When I try to `rake db:migrate`, I get this strange error before any attempt to even create the first table (yes, I started with `rake db:create`):

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'myapp_dev.usage_roles' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `usage_roles`
# ... followed by a long stack trace
```

I can't guess why the rake task is trying to show fields from any table before any should exist. I don't even see much mention of this table in the app. Here's the complete grep:

```
$ grep -r usage_roles .
Binary file ./.git/index matches
./app/models/usage/role.rb:  self.table_name = 'usage_roles'
./app/models/usage/user.rb:    where(" usage_roles.name in (?)", Usage::Role::SUPPORT_ROLES)
./coverage/index.html:          <code class="ruby">  self.table_name = 'usage_roles'</code>
./coverage/index.html:          <code class="ruby">    where(&quot; usage_roles.name in (?)&quot;, Usage::Role::SUPPORT_ROLES)</code>
./db/migrate/20130112104233_create_usage_roles.rb:    execute('CREATE VIEW usage_roles AS SELECT 
./db/migrate/20130112104233_create_usage_roles.rb:            * FROM clu_enums.usage_roles;')
./db/migrate/20130112104233_create_usage_roles.rb:    execute('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS usage_roles;')
```

Comment: Do any of the migration have any sql embedded in them or are they all 'pure' rails migrations?

Comment: You can see embedded sql in the grep above, but as I hinted before, it looks as though none of the migrations is even getting loaded.

Comment: I can't understand why, but when I set `factory_girl_rails` to `require:false` in my Gemfile, I can rake. Any idea what the explanation is?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is directly related to how Factorygirl handles databases. When you set `factory_girl_rails` to `require:false` that seems to be the solution.

Take a look at this [FactoryGirl screws up rake db:migrate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423273/factorygirl-screws-up-rake-dbmigrate-process)