# Rails: preventing spec files from being initialized during rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, rspec-rails, rake-task

I have a Rails app with a spec folder full of rspec tests. Many of them reference resources in my app, such as the 'User' resource. Everything is fine on my machine, but when I try to setup the app on a new machine and build the database with `rake db:setup`, it starts the whole Rails app, and for some reason, parts of the rspec tests get evaluated. Since one of them is referencing the 'User' resource, for which a database table has not been created yet, the rake task fails with `relation "users" does not exist`.

I can easily solve this my moving the spec folder out of the parent directory, running the setup, and then moving it back, but this is annoying. Obviously, I'd like for the spec files to be ignored during rake tasks like this. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't try it right now to verify it, but I guess you should be able to remove the spec folder from `config.autoload_paths` in application.rb

Answer (score 0):

This SO Answer helped me: [FactoryGirl screws up rake db:migrate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423273/factorygirl-screws-up-rake-dbmigrate-process).

This is the specific solution that worked for me.

In your gemfile, change factory_girls_rails so it isn't required

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
```

Then require it in your spec helper

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```