# Rails 4.0.1 on Heroku, can't create database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I can't get rake db:migrate to run on my rails 4.0.1 app on Heroku.

I'm guessing that I don't have postgres configured properly... but reading the docs on heroku hasn't really helped and I'm not sure what to do. I don't know too much about heroku or postgres.

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's anything else I can post.

(Also, I'm using devise, if that matters)

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get this:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5077
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum

rake aborted!
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

When I run `heroku run rake db:setup` I get this:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

... stack trace ...

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"aqofwrwjifcqkx", "password"=>"7yqDAx1L_4HFhw7WV3PH7ZrKyM", "port"=>5432, "database"=>"d5dvi0pjk7dgr7", "host"=>"ec2-23-21-94-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
```

followed by the same PG::UndefinedTable ERROR relation 'users' does not exist

database.yml :

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: chore_app_development
  pool: 5

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: chore_app_test
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chore_app_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Database
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Assets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Heroku
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Application
gem 'devise'
gem 'formtastic'

# Testing
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: added it to the post @jason328

Comment: Do you have the postgresql add-on in you Heroku app resources page?

Comment: Yes I have Heroku Postgresql :: Olive, apparently

Comment: Do I need to put the user and password from here in my database.yml? If so, would I then have to remove the file from version control (private repo, but still)

Comment: Heroku will recreate the database.yml for you so you it doesn't matter what you put in that file or if it even exists in the app.

Comment: Your database creds are in your question. Rotate them immediately by running `heroku pg:credentials HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR --reset --app your-app` https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/7/17/rotate_database_credentials_on_heroku_postgres_/

Comment: @GregB good call, thanks!

Comment: Do you perhaps have some logic in an initializer that is attempting to use the users relationship (before it exists in the database)?

Comment: @NathanHyde I don't think so. I just went through all my initializers and most of them are just empty scaffolds. There is a devise.rb but it just seems to set a bunch of config variables? I don't see it calling users anywhere.

Even so, I don't think that would prevent rake db:setup from being able to create the database, no?

Comment: Are you trying to drop a table in any of your migrations?

Comment: @fatfrog Migrations were sound, turned out to be FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should've read the stack trace more closely. My factories.rb was creating user objects as attributes for other factories. Wrapping them in a block fixed it:

[FactoryGirl screws up rake db:migrate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423273/factorygirl-screws-up-rake-dbmigrate-process)

Comment: I would recommend installing a local copy of PostgreSQL or creating a development instance of PostgresSQL on Heroku [1] and connecting to it remotely from your dev machine. This will ensure the same behavior in dev as in production. [1] https://www.heroku.com/postgres

Answer (score 52):

I would first try

```
heroku restart

heroku rake db:migrate
```

If that doesn't work, then try.

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL   #Literally type in heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL

heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I tried already. The output above is from running `heroku run rake db:migrate`, running heroku restart or heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL doesn't change the error.

Doing heroku pg:reset and then migrating also produces the same error.

Comment: sometimes the simplest explanation is the right one

Comment: @user2043725 your case can be different but it helps - as in my case

Comment: For those who are dumb like me, the command is literally `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL`. I was trying to find out what's my "database_url", but you don't need to worry about that (it's an environment variable set on Heroku). Just type `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` and be happy. Thanks for answer, Jason :)

Comment: @FernandoPaladini, oh, hell, thanks. I've been having trouble with this for hours before I stumbled upon your comment.

Comment: @lakesare, I actually mention this comment in my answer. It must not be prominent enough for others to see. I'll fix that.

Comment: @jason328, great, thanks. I did notice that in your answer after I read fernando's comment, I'd not pay attention otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

and you are done.

Comment: Literally, "DATABASE_URL" (I was initially confused wondering what I should substitute in there)

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Yes Literally :-). Its actually is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Jason's answer might fix your problem, but I wanted to expand on why you got the error and how to fix it.

1. You can't run "rake db:setup" on Heroku, because it will try to create a database, and your database already exists on Heroku
2. In your database.yml, you should read the database url from the environment variable like: 
   production: `url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>`
3. I think you are getting the 2nd error because you have some version error in your migrations, runing them from the begining should fix it :
   `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`

Answer (score 0):

To drop and recreate database

1. Login to heroku in terminal
2. cd into your app
3. Run

> heroku pg:reset DATABASE