# Setting up PostgresQL on Heroku Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

its been a while since i have used postgresql and deployed an app to Heroku, think I have made an error somewhere with my setup.

I have created my app on Heroku, there is a Hobby Dev database setup (`I ran Heroku run rake db:setup`) which set up my database, but I'm wondering in my `database.yml` file do i have an error

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
# For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: 5

production:
<<: *default
database: my_app_production
username: my_app
password: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

When I run `heroku run rake db:create` i get

```
 FATAL:  permission denied for database
 DETAIL:  User does not have   CONNECT privilege.

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"databaseName", "username"=>"userName", "password"=>"password", "port"=>5432, "host"=>"hostNamehere"}
```

I have set the database password using `heroku config:set`

What have i missed here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set password for postgres `heroku config:set MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORd='password'`

Comment: yes i have done that, but i will update that in the question to avoid confusion, thanks

Comment: can you put the logs you are getting.. or try this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293895/rails-4-0-1-on-heroku-cant-create-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku ignores your `database.yml` configuration, they generate one when you deploy your application and they also take care of database creation.
All you need to do is `heroku run rake db:migrate` and maybe a `heroku run rake db:seed` in case you need to seed your database.

Comment: well that makes everything nice and easy then :-) Thank You

Comment: because i need to wait 7 mins before I can accept :)