# Migration to create table raises Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I wrote a migration with the following:

```
class CreateTableSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :some_tables do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, references: :user, foreign_key: true
      t.text :summary
    end
  end
end
```

It is a basic migration that is creating a database table.  However: when I run `rails db:migrate` a very odd error message aborts the migration:

> Mysql2::Error: Table 'my_database.some_tables' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM 'some_tables'

It is as if the error is saying it can't create the table because the table does exist, which doesn't make sense.

Things I have looked at and tried:

- reviewed the database.yml which seems fine.  Nothing has changed, and I have recently run other migrations just fine (though no migrations that created database tables)
- ran `bundle` to ensure all gems were installed
- deleted the `schema.rb` file, recreated the database with data from another copy, and I ran `rake db:schema:dump` to recreate the `schema.rb` file.  I attempted to run the migration again and still got the same error.

I am using `rails 5.1.1` as well as `mysql2 0.4.6`

Any tips on how I can get the migration to run?

Comment: It looks like you have your ducks in a row, so this is probably a redundant question, but: Have you verified that it is this specific migration causing the problem, by, for example, putting debug code in the migration, or using an environment variable to cause just the one migration to be run?  What shows up in the log file, when you run the migration, that is related to this table?

Comment: Try running `rake db:migrate:status` to see the migrations that have been applied to the database. Maybe you find out you are connecting to a different schema, or you discover that the migration that is failing is not the one you think is causing the failure.

Comment: My issue was different AND using a different ORM, but leaving a comment to help others who might be going through something similar... 
My migration was a mixture of ORM syntax and raw SQL, and I had initially declared the table name as a constant to be reused throughout as needed. Turns out the error was b/c I was interpolating the table name incorrectly within the SQL (too many quotation marks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a work around, but it is still very puzzling to me.

The error message in the log file was not exactly pointing to the issue.  For some reason, it might be `rails 5.1.1` or it might be `mysql2 0.4.6`, but it doesn't like using `references` within the `create_table` block for some reason. Very odd because it has worked for me in the past.

So I changed the migration from this:

```
class CreateTableSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :some_tables do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, references: :user, foreign_key: true
      t.text :summary
    end
  end
end
```

To this:

```
class CreateTableSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :some_tables do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :author_id
      t.text :summary
    end
  end
end
```

And it worked.

It is very odd because `references` works just fine with `sqlite3` (I  tested this by generating a dummy app, ran a scaffold command with a `references` column, and ran `rails db:migrate` and it all worked).

Comment: Interesting.  Might be a bug in the adapter.  Anyhow, Thanks for recording the resolution.  This may help someone else having the same problem.

Comment: `t.references :author, references: :user, foreign_key: true` this may be your issue too because you are passing `references: :user` as a `option` to the column definition. This may be a case of a bubble up error resulting in the message you mentioned. (Although looking through the `active_record` source I cannot see a reason why this would not just be ignored as an `option`)

Comment: @engineersmnky I did consider that.  I tested removing that `reference` line altogether which left only the simple reference line of: `t.references :user, foreign_key: true`.  Unfortunately it still errored out.

Answer (score 34):

I got a similar error when trying to create a new model that has a reference to an existing model that was created before migrating to Rails 5.1.

Although the error message was not very clear about that, in my case it turned out that the problem was data type mismatch between the primary key of the old model and the foreign key of the new model (MySQL does not permit that). It was so because since Rails 5.1 the default data type of all the primary and foreign keys is bigint, but for the old model the primary key type was still integer.

I solved this by converting all the primary and foreign keys of the current models to bigint, so I can use the Rails new defaults and forget about it.

A workaround could also be specifying integer type for the new foreign keys so that they match the primary keys type of the old models. Something like the following:

```
class CreateUserImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :user_images do |t|
      t.references :user, type: :integer, foreign_key: true
      t.string :url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

The big issue with the ActiveRecord migration 5.1 is that now the id are expected to be BIGINT instead of INT, so when you adding a column referring another table created before rails 5.1 it expect the column type to be BIGINT but instead is just an INT, hence the error.
The best solution is just modify your migration and change the type of the column to int.

```
class CreateTableSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  create_table :some_tables do |t|
   t.references :user, foreign_key: true, type: :int
   t.references :author, references: :user, foreign_key: true
   t.text :summary
  end
end
```

that should work.

Comment: It's it, but I think the error should be more explicit, because I can't see the tips to the solution reading the message. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts, I think I was seeing a different reason for this than what others suggested.  In my case it happened because my migration file names didn't exactly match the migration class therein.  For example, I had a migration file named `20171205232654_bonus.rb` but inside the class was declared as `class CreateBonus < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`.  Once I changed the file name to `20171205232654_create_bonus.rb` everything worked.

This might have something to do with the fact that I've been creating migrations only, not full scaffolds, and maybe I did something wrong.  I really don't know how I wound up with that mismatch.